# How to upload a file to a server

Tags: java, file-upload, noclassdeffounderror

I am making an app that uploads a file on the server, the app has 2 buttons, one is browse and the other is upload. But when i hit the upload button it crashes. I get these errors:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/Consts    at
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MIME.(MIME.java:48)   at
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.(MultipartEntity.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.(MultipartEntity.java:91)
>     at UploadFile.(UploadFile.java:27)    at
>   Frame$3.actionPerformed(Frame.java:64)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.Consts  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 41 more

The code from the buttons:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Browse");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser x = new JFileChooser();
                if(x.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    String file = x.getSelectedFile().toString();
                    textField.setText(file);

                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(182, 11, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnUpload = new JButton("Upload");
        btnUpload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new UploadFile(textField.getText());
            }
        });
```

The upload function:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UploadFile {
    public UploadFile(String alamat) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");
        File file = new File(alamat);
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "text/plain");
        mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println("Executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UploadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file uploaded succesfully");
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you run your app?

Comment: Add this to your classpath: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5

Comment: What are you using to build your project? You'd need at least some dependency management like maven or have the accompanying dependencies in a classpath. I'd suggest you show us more of your setup so we can help you better?

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)